# Hibernate configuration (custom type override) using Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to configure `hibernate` type overriding using `Spring` and `Spring Data JPA`?
Using hibernate I did following:

```
configuration.registerTypeOverride(new CustomType);
```

Since I'm using Spring `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` I'm not aware if I can do it or not. Is it possible?